# Cross joining(combine each line of one file with other file) files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have three files and i want to cross join (or combine) each line of one file with other.
EX) File1 contains

```
a,b,c   

d,e,f
```

File2 :

```
1,2,3

4,5,6
```

so i want output like :

```
a,b,c,1,2,3

a,b,c,4,5,6

d,e,f,1,2,3

d,e,f,4,5,6
```

I could do this in python with loops one inside other , but if we have more than 4 files there would be multiple loops .

Is there any other way in python to resolve this in efficient way?

Comment: Oops, you're looking for the nested iteration (aka cartesian product) of the two files, not the lockstep iteration of them. The answer to that is [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Since you tagged this with `numpy`, you could load each file into an array, join the arrays appropriately, and write a new file.  This will be easiest if all data is numeric, but it can also be done with strings.